# Stripe not Throwing Charging Error in Python

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe library in Python for credit card charging.  I use the customerID for purposes of charging rather than the token as I want to re-use the card without asking for it each time.  The success process works just fine, however, if I create an error condition the "except" is never thrown.  I am testing the failure state by using an invalid customer ID.

The server log shows the following error: "InvalidRequestError: Request req_8949iJfEmeX39p: No such customer: 22" but again this is not handled in try/except.

```
class ChargeCustomerCard(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    stripe.api_key = stripeApiKey
    customerID = self.request.get("cust")
    amount = self.request.get("amt")

    try:
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(amount=int(amount),currency="usd",customer=customerID,description=customerID)
    except stripe.error.CardError, e:
        output = {"result":e}
    else:
        output = {"result":"1"}

    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(output))
```

Comment: Add another `except Exception as e` clause below the specific `stripe.error.CardError` and before the `else` of your `try` block, and see if that gives you the appropriate error. If so, you may want to file an issue at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues unless it was intended not to be a stripe specific Exception/Error, or maybe there is another specific Error under `stripe.error` namespace you need to `except`

Comment: Yes, that is the correct approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=python#errors you're not handling all the possible errors/exceptions that the stripe library supplies. And dealing with financial data rightfully deserves even more caution so you really need to do at least something like:

```
class ChargeCustomerCard(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        stripe.api_key = stripeApiKey
        customerID = self.request.get("cust")
        amount = self.request.get("amt")

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(amount=int(amount),currency="usd",customer=customerID,description=customerID)
        except stripe.error.CardError, e:
            output = {"result":e}
        except Exception as e:
            # handle this e, which could be stripe related, or more generic
            pass
        else:
            output = {"result":"1"}

        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(output))
```

Or even based on the official documentation, a more comprehensive one like:

```
try:
    # Use Stripe's library to make requests...
    pass
except stripe.error.CardError, e:
    # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
    body = e.json_body
    err  = body['error']

    print "Status is: %s" % e.http_status
    print "Type is: %s" % err['type']
    print "Code is: %s" % err['code']
    # param is '' in this case
    print "Param is: %s" % err['param']
    print "Message is: %s" % err['message']
except stripe.error.RateLimitError, e:
    # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
    pass
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError, e:
    # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    pass
except stripe.error.AuthenticationError, e:
    # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
    # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
    pass
except stripe.error.APIConnectionError, e:
    # Network communication with Stripe failed
    pass
except stripe.error.StripeError, e:
    # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
    # yourself an email
    pass
except Exception, e:
    # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
    pass
```

Comment: This is correct. In this instance, the exception that would be raised is `InvalidRequestError` as the customer ID is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for this approach!

Answer (score 2):

I think the official documentation could provide a bit more complete boilerplate. This is what I ended up with:

```
except stripe.error.RateLimitError, e:
    # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
    err = e.json_body['error']
    lg.error("Stripe RateLimitError: %s" % (err))
    ...
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError, e:
    # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    err = e.json_body['error']
    lg.error("Stripe InvalidRequestError: %s" % (err))
    ...
```

Which makes it a little more clear how you can deal with e to log some useful errors.