# Python-Stripe: How to catch stripe.error.CardError in Flask App

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I'm having the same problem as the OP here:
[Stripe not Throwing Charging Error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213823/stripe-not-throwing-charging-error-in-python)

Unfortunately the solution does not work for me, my error won't be caught.
I have a little route in Flask that takes in some data, does some DB work and finally will create a charge via stripe. I have currently two test cases, one which will test the route with the correct stripe token and valid cc data. This test passes. Another test is to check whether the route will return an error message when the card data is invalid. This test does not pass since the invalid card data error gets thrown. Part of my route code (which is copied from the stripe documentation):

```
try:
    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=total,
        currency='usd',
        description='XXX',
        source=stripe_token['id']
    )
except stripe.error.CardError as e:
    response_object = {
        'status': 'failure',
        'message': 'problem with the card'
    }
    return jsonify(response_object), 400
except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
    # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
    pass
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
    # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    pass
except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
    # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
    # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
    pass
except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
    # Network communication with Stripe failed
    pass
except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
    # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
    # yourself an email
    pass
except Exception as e:
    # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
    pass
```

Part of my test that fails:

```
def test_card_error(self):
    with self.client:
        token = stripe.Token.create(
          card={
              "number": '4242424242424242',
              "exp_month": 12,
              "exp_year": 2017,
              "cvc": '123'
            },
        )
        response = self.client.post(
            '/orders',
            headers=({'Authorization': 'Bearer *' }),
            data=json.dumps({
                'user_id': 'user',
                'status': 'created',
                'paid': False,
                'stripe_token': token,
                'items': [
                    {
                        'order_line_number': 1,
                        'theme_code': 1,
                        'quantity_ordered': 1,
                        'price_each': 2999,
                    }
                ]
            }),
            content_type = 'application/json'
        )
        data = json.loads(response.data.decode())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)
        self.assertIn('problem with the card', data['message'])
        self.assertIn('failure', data['status'])
```

What I would like is that my test passes because my route returns the response object with the message "problem with the card" and http code 400. But instead the test fails because of:

`ERROR: test_card_error (test_orders.TestOrdersService)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/project/tests/test_orders.py", line 63, in test_card_error
    "cvc": '123'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 17, in create
    response, api_key = requestor.request('post', url, params, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 153, in request
    resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 365, in interpret_response
    self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 178, in handle_error_response
    raise err
stripe.error.CardError: Request req_bIge4on6ZTyQfj: Your card's expiration year is invalid.`

So as I see it... the error is correct because I'm testing invalid card data. But I don't really see why the exception does not get handled. I'm probably just staring at this problem for too long and the solution is simple but please... enlighten me :D

EDIT:
The problem seems to lie within my test function and the "stripe.Token.create" part. Here the error occurs. Not in my route. The route never even gets fired.

Anybody got any idea how I can create a "wrong stripe token" so that I can properly test this?

Comment: Use a test card that declines.  https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses

`4000000000000002` if you don't care to attach it to a Customer first.

`4000000000000341` if you *do* want to attach it to a Customer first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @korben! My problem was that I was trying to create a token with the stripe library, which resulted in the error. I didn't know there were also test tokens!

Comment: If you'd like to test out the different variation of errors in your unit test, there are test sites like [Testing Pays](http://www.testingpays.com/) that offers support for Stripe APIs. You can use the simulated APIs from there to plug it in to your tests.